# ServiceStack Bundler and sub-directory Less files

Tags: css, less, servicestack

Until recentlly I was using the rather awkward dotless. I'm restricted to what I can use somewhat because I'm using VS2010, however I came across ServiceStack Bundler which seems to work great... apart from one thing.

My Less files are split using a directory structure - to simplify things, like this:

```
scaffolding/my-scaffolding.less
utilities/my-utilities.less
ui/my-ui.less
```

Each directories has many files, particularly with mixins etc.

In order to link them together, I've been using the `@import` function.

My main less file - main.less contains the following:

```
@import "utilities/all-utilities.less"
```

All utilities are listed here as it enables me to plug and play various file-sets. This code previously worked ok.

However I find ServiceStack won't pick up changes unless I reference all the less files individually and directly through the bundle file, which is a bit of a pain.

So, I can't use: `main.less` and import all sub files.

Instead, I have to use:

```
utilities/util1.less
utilities/util2.less
utilities/util3.less
```

and so on.

I'm using the ms build function to compile.

Any ideas?

/* UPDATE */

Tried the recommended answer below without success.

This is what I've tried so far:

**Call a single less file that contains all @import declarations;**
Does not trigger updates on compile.

**Call all less files from bundle file and add @import statements to less files where necessary (note bundler won't compile without these);**
Duplicates the @imported code as many times as the @import statement is used - even when (reference) directive is used, resulting in bloated/incorrect code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake on my part, but one which wasn't easily spottable, so I'll post the reason for my problems so that others don't spend hours as I did chasing a solution to an unecessary problem.

I was using ServiceStack Bundler - I believe this issue would also have occured on on any solution using npm's less library.

My main issue was that none of my changes were triggered on compile. I use lots of @imports and numerous sub-directories for my less files so my first thoughts were the problem was due to subdirectories, and later, due to @import statements. However neither was correct.

I defined a bundle: `main.css.bundle`

Within the bundle I called my main less file that contained all the other @imported files: `main.less`

The issue was that less would normally reserve main.css, but the bundle also gives its output the same name based on the bundle name. So both were conflicting.

Change the bundle name or the main less file name and all should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify Bundler's `bundler.js` file to [specify additional paths](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler/blob/master/src/bundler.js#L509) that less should search for when processing `@import` directives:

```
function compileLess(lessCss, lessPath, cb) {
    var lessDir = path.dirname(lessPath),
        fileName = path.basename(lessPath),
        options = {
            paths: ['.', lessDir], // Specify search paths for @import directives
            filename: fileName
        };

    less.render(lessCss, options, function (err, css) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(css);
    });
}
```

Comment: Well I'm truly honoured to get the answer from the main man. I'll assume it correct then :). Thanks a bundle - excuse the pun.

Comment: @dotnetnoob thx, tho that's how to pass additional path options to the less compiler, whether it works or not is up to npm's less library.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove the answer - I cannot get the paths option to work and am struggling to come up with a satisfactory solution.